# Custom serialization and deserialization is scala using jackson

Tags: java, scala, jackson

I have a JSON as a string which I am deserializing and instantiating as MyPOJO case class of scala. My data is in YYYY-MM-DD format but the actual attribute in POJO createdBy is LocalDateTime.

How to assign a default time value of 2020-03-02 00:00:00 while instantiating Pojo,

Serialization should return yyyy-mm-dd format. My serialization and deserialization format are different.

```
case class MyPOJO( @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-mm-dd" ) createdBy :LocalDateTime )

object MyJaxsonP {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val objectMapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
    objectMapper.findAndRegisterModules()
    objectMapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
    objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule)
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
    objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
    val adminDatasP = objectMapper.readValue[MyPOJO]("{\"createdBy\":\"2020-03-02\"}")
    print(adminDatasP.toString)
  }
}
```

I have tried with custom serialization and deserialization, like below, but is not working saying default constructor is missing

```
case class MyPOJO( @JsonDeserialize(using = classOf[CustomDateDeserializer] ) createdBy :LocalDateTime ) 

object CustomDateDeserializer {
  private val formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")
}

class CustomDateDeserializer(val t: Class[String]) extends StdDeserializer[String](t) {

  override def deserialize(p: JsonParser, ctxt: DeserializationContext): String = {
    val date = p.getText
    return CustomDateDeserializer.formatter.format(date);
  }
}
```

Need expert input on how to solve this problem

Comment: Is this acceptable to you to consider another lib then Jackson or you forced to use it? I'm wondering, because this issue can be easily solved with libs like `circe` - which more famous in Scala world. Thanks.

Comment: what's different in circe and how can I use Custom DateDeserializer in scala

Comment: The main advantage, that `circe` generates JSON codec for case class in compile time - or in another words, if for any type `T` JSON codec is missing you will know this is compile time and you don't need plug additional modules, like for Jackson and use additional annotations (because it is not reflection based unlike Jackson). Also, it's quite simple to override behavior for some type for particular class. Would you like me to post an example with `circe`?

Comment: And excuse me, I forgot to mention that case classes does not have default (or empty if you will) constructor - they are immutable, hence requires data at creation moment. So you will not be able to create case class instance, and then inject values via reflection. Another option - create plain class and implement all necessary `get*`, `hashCode`, `equals` and `toString` methods by yourself.

Comment: Can you share some examples in context of my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but is not working saying default constructor is missing

You getting the error, because there is not default or empty, if you will, constructor for case classes. In this particular case when you declare `case class MyPOJO(createdBy : LocalDateTime)` scala compiler will generate something like (example might be not very accurate, I want just to show an idea):

```
class MyPOJO(createdBy : LocalDateTime) extends Product with Serializeble {
  override def hashCode(): Int = ...
  override def equals(oterh: Any): Boolean = ...
  override def toString(): String = ...
  // and other methods, like copy, unaply, tupled etc.
}

object MyPOJO {
  def apply(createdBy : LocalDateTime) = new MyPOJO(createdBy)
}
```

so Jackson wont be able to create empty class instance with empty fields (or `null` values more precisely) and then inject values from source JSON.

What you can do - use plain class instead of case classes. Or, what is more preferable, to take a look on Scala friendly JSON libraries like [Circe](https://circe.github.io/circe/) which is not reflection based, unlike Jackson, and instead generates JSON codec in compile time for some classes, based on implicit's and Scala macros (more precisely it relies on `Shapeless` library which uses Scala macros mechanism under the hood).

In your particular case, code would look like:

```
    import io.circe._
    import io.circe.generic.auto._
    import io.circe.syntax._

    case class MyPOJO(createdBy: LocalDateTime)
    val format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")

    // Implement own `Encoder` to render `LocalDateTime` as JSON string, separated with comma inside
    implicit val encoder: Encoder[LocalDateTime] = Encoder[String].contramap(_.format(format))

    // Implement own `Decoder` to parse JSON string as `LocalDateTime`
    implicit val decoder: Decoder[LocalDateTime] = Decoder[String].
      emapTry(value => Try(LocalDate.parse(value, format).atStartOfDay()))

    val foo = MyPOJO(LocalDateTime.now())
    val json = foo.asJson

    println(json.noSpaces)
    println(json.as[MyPOJO])
```

which will produce next result:

```
{"createdBy":"2020-03-04"}
Right(MyPOJO(2020-03-04T00:00))
```

Hope this helps!